# What is the AT&T / GAS syntax for mulx?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

The [Wikibooks x86 Assembly](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax) says:

> GAS instructions generally have the form mnemonic source, destination. For instance, the following mov instruction:

But it does not say what exceptions to this rule are, and I cannot find a table of instructions.  The [official AS documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/) doesn't seem to have a section that gives syntax for all the instructions (though it's pretty long, and I might have just missed the section).  The [normal x86 reference that I use for instructions](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MULX.html) doesn't obviously specify the dialect, though, and it has the arguments in destination, source order.

What's the syntax for `mulx` in GAS / AT&T, and is there a reference that I can use to easily look up such things in the future?

Comment: When in doubt, assemble using one syntax, disassemble using the other. Anyway, it's reversed as usual.

Comment: and/or since you have the reference (which you should be using anyway in general despite syntax)  try to insert the machine code .word or .byte or DB or whatever and then disassemble...

Comment: @Jester does "reversed" mean "list reversal", i.e., source, low_dst, high_dst, or does "reversed" mean "flip source and target", i.e., cycle the list, i.e., source, high_dst, low_dst?

Comment: Simple list reversal.

Comment: Someone should really update those docs :/  x86 instructions with more than 2 operands are common these days (AVX and so on).

Comment: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MULX.html is an extract from Intel's volume 2 PDF (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm#three-volume), which does specify the dialect in detail (dest is always the left-mode operand in Intel syntax, then src1, src2, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wikibook: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Arithmetic

doesn't include MULX, but it does show the 3 operand IMUL instruction listed as such:

```
imul    dest, src, aux                  (Intel syntax)
imul    aux, src, dest                  (GAS Syntax)
```

so MULX would be:

```
mulx    dest_hi, dest_lo, src1          (Intel syntax)
mulx    src1, dest_lo, dest_hi          (GAS Syntax)
```