# Efficient multiplication by a power of 2 in x86 Assembly code (GAS syntax) without affecting flags

Tags: assembly, x86, inline-assembly, att

Suppose that we have the following piece of assembly code:

```
mulx const, %rax, %r11
```

where const is a hard-coded constant, which is known to be a power of two (let us assume for concreteness that it is 2^24).
According to https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-large-integer-arithmetic-paper.pdf page 8:

> The `mulx` instruction is an extension of the existing `mul` instruction, with the
> difference being in the effect on flags:
>
> ```
> mulx dest_hi, dest_lo, src1
> ```
>
> The instruction also uses an implicit src2 register, `edx` or `rdx` depending on
> whether the 32-bit or 64-bit version is being used.
> The operation is:
>
> ```
> dest_hi:dest_lo = src1 * r/edx
> ```

Converting to GAS syntax (See also [What is the AT&T / GAS syntax for mulx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46161130/what-is-the-att-gas-syntax-for-mulx)) we should have in our case:

```
%r11:%rax = const * %rdx
```

In our case, we want to find an equivalent piece of code not involving the multiplication (and not modifying the flags). We could write:

```
movq %rdx, %r11
movq %rdx, %rax
shl $24, %rax
shr $40, %r11
```

but this is modifying the carry flag. I tried also with some other variants of the shift instructions (which are not modifying flags), but they give an error.
My computer has an Intel Core i7 processor.

Comment: That should be equivalent; are you sure you had the right value for your `mulx` source operand?  If you actually wrote `myconst: .quad 2^24`, you'd get an assemble-time XOR operation, not exponentiation.  None of those instructions read CF, but of course they have different effects on CF if you're considering that an output.  (shifts set CF, `mulx` leaves all FLAGS unmodified.)

Comment: What Peter said.  Please provice a [mcve] and expected vs. actual output.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks. Actually the situation is the following:
I am using the macro llvm_asm! of Rust. I don't want the carry flags to be changed (so we can say that I consider them as an output). 
I saw that should use the shift commands shlx/salx and shrx/sarx, in order to avoid carry flags updates. Nevertheless it looks that they are not recognized.
The error message is "invalid operand for instruction".

Comment: You should edit your question to be clearer about CF being the output you care about, and that that's the only difference in output. 
 That's very unusual in general; most x86 instructions step on flags.  (And GNU C inline asm has an implicit "cc" clobber for i386 and x86-64 targets; IDK if Rust inline asm might be different.) SHLX/SHRX are only available with register sources, unfortunately, as per the ISA reference https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sarx:shlx:shrx.  The only flagless shift that takes an immediate is actually a rotate, BMI2 RORX.

Comment: Probably useless ideas: `lea` lets you shift by 1, 2 or 3.  `rorx $56, %rax, %rax ; mov $0, %al` shifts by 8. `rorx $48, %rax, %rax ; mov $0, %ax` shifts by 16.

Answer (score 3):

SHLX/SHRX are only available with register sources, unfortunately, as per the ISA reference https://felixcloutier.com/x86/sarx:shlx:shrx. The only flagless shift that takes an immediate is actually a rotate, BMI2 RORX.

So they'd work for this (and avoid the `mov` instructions) if you had `40` and `24` in registers.  That would get the job done in 2 uops (for ports 0 or 6 on HSW / SKL / ICL), if you can hoist the shift-count register setup out of a loop.

---

64-bit `mulx` with register sources is also only 2 uops on Intel HSW / SKL / ICL, for ports 1 and 5 (https://uops.info).  (3 uops for 32-bit operand-size, perhaps an extra one to split the multiply unit's low-64 output into 32-bit halves.)  So it's an interesting option if you can't hoist the constant setup and would need to `mov $1<<24, %edx` to set up for it.

You'd want to be careful of `mulx` bottlenecking on its 3c / 4c latency, or on port 1 (or maybe 5) throughput on Intel CPUs if you have other multiplies or other things that need specific ports.  With register constants already set up, it's generally worse than SHLX/SHRX, except for code-size.

---

It's rare that there's much benefit from not clobbering FLAGS.  It does happen sometimes, but since most ALU instructions do write FLAGS, it's hard to *not* do so.  So much so that GNU C inline asm for x86(-64) has an implicit `"cc"` clobber.